# How to handle NHibernate mapping join with duplicate column name

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

Here is my problem.

I have two tables **StudentSchoolAssociation** and **StudentSchoolAssociationExtension**. As the names imply, one is an extension of the other.

**StudentSchoolAssociation** is a table that cannot be added to as it is a Standards Based Table, which is where the Extension table comes in.

The problem I have is that the base **StudentSchoolAssociation** table contains a column for **SchoolYear** and the extension table needs a column named **SchoolYear** for a foreign key reference to a table called **SchoolCalendar**.

This creates a situation where when I add the join in my NHibernate mapping file

```xml
<join table="StudentSchoolAssociationExtension" schema="extension">
  <key>
    <column name="EntryDate" />
    <column name="SchoolId" />
    <column name="StudentUSI" />
  </key>
  <property name="HomelessMcKinneyServedIndicator" />
  <property name="HomelessUnaccompaniedIndicator" />
  <property name="SESAppliedIndicator" />
  <property name="SESReceivingIndicator" />
  <property name="CompletionDocumentDescriptorId" />
  <property name="CompletionDocumentPeriodDescriptorId" />
  <property name="TotalInstructionalMins" />
  <property name="StudentStandardDayEffectiveDate" type="date" />
  <property name="CompletionDocumentDate" type="date" />
  <property name="SchoolCalendarNumber" />
  <property name="LocalEducationAgencyId" />
  <property name="DistrictCalendarNumber" />
  <property name="SchoolYear" type="short" />
</join>
```

I get a duplicate column exception.

My question is if anyone knows a best practices way to work with this problem. Keep in mind that **StudentSchoolAssociation** is iron locked and CAN NOT be altered and a FK reference to the **SchoolCalendar** table is needed on the extension table.

Comment: I assume that SchoolYear on the Extension table represents something different than SchoolYear on the base table?  Otherwise you would, of course, not need both.  Assuming they are representing different things, I would suggest changing the name of the column in the Extension table, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really a duplicated column exception? I bet it is a duplicated property exception instead.

Try:

```
<join table="StudentSchoolAssociationExtension" schema="extension">
  ...
  <property name="ExtendedSchoolYear" column="SchoolYear" type="short" />
</join>
```

Of course, add in your extended entity definition an `ExtendedSchoolYear` property.

Comment: You're right, it is a duplicated property exception. Was recalling from memory.

Just came back to answer my question with what you answered with just with a different name attribute. You beat me to it! Thanks for your answer.